# How to prevent files from being virtualized, i.e. copied from ProgramData folder into AllUsers folder?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7, programdata

I'm storing application data in the

```
C:\ProgramData folder.
```

I want to prevent this data from being copied into

```
C:\Users\All Users\
```

What do I need to do in my application to disable this functionality?

Comment: Aren't those just the same location anyways?  `C:\Users\All Users` is a link (or whatever is the correct terminology) to `C:\ProgramData` (had it backwards, confirmed in explorer).

Comment: This specific kind of virtualization is in place to handle misbehaving legacy applications.

Is there a particular reason why you *need* it to use C:\ProgramData ?

Comment: @ChrisO is right (well.. sort of). `C:\Users\All Users` is a symbolic link to `C:\ProgramData`. `C:\ProgramData` is the "real" location while `C:\Users\All Users` is there just for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\All Users` is a symbolic link to `C:\ProgramData`. `C:\ProgramData` is the "real" location while `C:\Users\All Users` is there just for compatibility.

So nothing is actually copied to `C:\Users\All Users`, it just points to `C:\ProgramData` where the files actually are.

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/bb756982)

**Edit:** I found this [somehow-similar SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/405097/are-c-programdata-and-c-users-all-users-the-same-do-i-need-both)